# Excel - Looking to Generate Break/Lunch/On/Off in Gantt Chart format

Tags: excel

Excel - Looking to Generate Break/Lunch/On/Off in Gantt Chart format

Looking to generate a Gantt Chart from a timesheet format.

I've been able to change it based on the basic time range using:

> =IF(R1=MEDIAN($B$2,$I$2,R1),"30","OFF")

I am at a loss building the nested IF AND THEN parts for inputing the breaks and lunches in between automatically.

[image: Spreadsheet Screenshot]

**Google Sheet Example:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UgBDIk6pvFoFa_MwB5eWS7YZqVbTKjWBMeP9SM6X5Ag/edit?usp=sharing

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated